# TestContainers Oracle TimeoutException

Tags: java, docker, junit, integration-testing, testcontainers

I tried to use [testcontainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java-module-oracle-xe) library for integration tests with Oracle. Here is is the simple test:

```
public class SimpleTest {

    @Rule
    public OracleContainer oracle = new OracleContainer();

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() throws SQLException {
        HikariDataSource ds = buildHikariDataSource();
        Statement statement = ds.getConnection().createStatement();
        statement.execute("SELECT 1 FROM dual");
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();

        resultSet.next();
        int resultSetInt = resultSet.getInt(1);
        assertEquals("A basic SELECT query succeeds", 1, resultSetInt);
    }

    private HikariDataSource buildHikariDataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(oracle.getJdbcUrl());
        hikariConfig.setUsername(oracle.getUsername());
        hikariConfig.setPassword(oracle.getPassword());
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }
}

But it fails with TimeoutException:

Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:256)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$start$0(GenericContainer.java:184)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:76)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:53)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:81)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:235)
    ... 20 more
```

My Docker installation is suitable with testcontainers-oracle-xe and os is macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

How can this problem be resolved?

P.S. [Full console output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OQYd0PzV-dwFdQao-qzyqupZpMnYdRru)

Comment: Could you post the full stack-trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All in all I created an [issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java-module-oracle-xe/issues/8) in testcontainers-java-module-oracle-xe repository.

The solution was to change location to US and language to English in System Preferences.

The answer from testcontainers engineer:

> My colleague have faced the same problem. We have debugged and
>   understood that problem with oracle TNS (ORA-12514). In order to
>   resolve it, there is a need to change language to English and location
>   to US.